# run a .jar file in web browser

Tags: java, html

I have a java program, or .jar file. It has to be run in the web browser automatically.
In web page which has a button when clicked, it should download that .jar file and has to run in user's browser.

Is it possible ?. Any suggestions.

Comment: Have a look at [Java Web Start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to make your program into an Applet. Check out Oracle's guide for help. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/